# Regex to extract date, month and year seeparately from dd/mm/yy and month dd, yyyy

Tags: regex, datetime

I need to extract date information from two dates:

```
Monday, Sep 1, 2014 10:00 AM
```

and

```
01/09/14
```

such that I have day (01), month (09) and year(2014)

I was able to extract the day (01) with this regex:

```
\s+.*?(\d+)\/*,*
```

I've had no luck with extracting year and I'm completely clueless on how to extract month.
Kindly help.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: How regex would know `Sep` is a month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combined regex. You can get both forms from it.

If it's "Monday, Sep 1, 2014" format the capture groups will be:

```
1: Sep
3: 1
4: 2014
```

and for "01/01/14" they will be:

```
2: 01
3: 01
4: 14
```

Just check if the second group exists for checking if the value is the second format:

```
^\w*(?:, (\w{3})|(\d{2}))[\/ ]\s*(\d{1,2})(?:/|, )(\d{2,4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/C0mNu7LP8vPRcUbl)

Explanation:

1. begin at string begin
2. skip optional weekday
3. A: skip ", " and then take the 3 letter month
4. B: take the first number
5. skip " " or /
6. take second number (1 in "Sep 1")
7. skip / or ", "
8. take 2-4 year code

Comment: Can you suggest how to parse the dates using this regex using SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 1):

The first date can be extracted with the following:

```
\w+,\s\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM)
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cY4dQ9/1)

The main parts here are the number are limited to the respectively digits. ie. a year can only be 4 digits and month/day can only be 2 digits. You could take this a step farther if needed, but this is usually enough to prevent any false-positives within the data you're parsing.

The second date can be extracted like the following:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}
```

Again, the individual pieces of the date are restricted to two digits to try and reduce the number of false positive. This will catch false positives if there's other date formats within the data. In that case, it will need to be limited more. There's a couple more things you could do, but it really depends on your data.

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pB0yL4/1)

Then if you'd like to combine the two regexes, one way would be to do the following:

```
(?:\w+,\s\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM)|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iL7hO0/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data from first date using:
`(.+),\s(\.+)\s(\d+),.*`

and from the first date using:
`(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)`

Just if you sure about the format of you date outputs.